# Non SUDO command for Ram Slot related Information

Tags: linux, ssh, memory

I am using plink in windows to SSH linux machine.
I need to find out Ram and slot details of the Linux machine.I have written a shell script to fetch the details of the same and show it in a JSON format.

But the problem is I have used

```
dmidecode --type 17
```

for getting the ram details.It needs to be run that command as a Sudo user. I can use "-t" option in SSH to pass the password. But that is not desired. The output should not be Interactive.

When I pass

> Plink.exe -l login -pw password HOSTNAME -m "MySHellScriptFile.sh"

it should show the result.
But I can't achieve that with SUDO command,since it will ask for password. I can't even use `lshw -class memory`, since it also needs Sudo permission to show slot related details of ram.
I need Bank Locator,Speed, Type , Ram Size. Is there any way to find  those details with Non Sudo command? Or Is there any way to pass the password for  SUDO commands in the plink itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup sudo to allow the user to use sudo with no password, and be able to run only that one command.

I would recommend creating a new file in /etc/sudoers.d/ and putting the following lines into it

```
Cmnd_Alias GET_RAM = lshw -class memory
user ALL = GET_RAM    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That config is off the top of my head, so give it a shot and see how you go.
Just replace user with your user, and make sure you have a spare root session open in case you stuff up sudo :)

Comment: I am in the network and I am running Plink inside a application to get Ram details. So it is not desired to alter the client machine for Application purpose.